# I can't find a button using id or xpath using pagefactory on expedia.com website

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't find a button using id or xpath using pagefactory on expedia.com website. It says no such element: Unable to locate element "tab-flight-tab-flp".
I tried using id and xpath. It gives same error. I wonder this is happening?
It says no such element: Unable to locate element "tab-flight-tab-flp".
I tried using id and xpath. It gives same error. I wonder this is happening?
It says no such element: Unable to locate element "tab-flight-tab-flp".
I tried using id and xpath. It gives same error. I wonder this is happening?

```html
package UsefulPackages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class SearchPageFactory {      

       WebDriver adriver;     

       @FindBy(id="tab-flight-tab-flp")
       WebElement flightTab;      
      
       //constructor
       public SearchPageFactory(WebDriver driver) {

             this.adriver = driver;
             PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
       }     

       public void clickFlightTab(){            

             flightTab.click();          

       }     

}
```

```html
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import UsefulPackages.SearchPageFactory;

public class FrameworkTestCase {

       WebDriver achromeDriver;
       String abaseUrl;

      SearchPageFactory apagefactory;            

       @Before
       public void setUp() throws Exception {                            

             abaseUrl = "http://www.expedia.com";                           

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\ChromeDirver\\chromedriver.exe");                           

            achromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();                           

            apagefactory = new SearchPageFactory(achromeDriver);                           

            chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            achromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();
            System.out.println("setup completed");

       }            

      @Test

         public void test() {                            

               achromeDriver.get(abaseUrl);                                                         

               WebDriverWait awaittime = new WebDriverWait(achromeDriver, 10);      

               System.out.println("page factory created");                           

                apagefactory.clickFlightTab();
              }

 

 

}
```

Comment: I can't find that id either. if you are looking to click on flight tab ,then here is the correct id - id='tab-flight-tab-hp'

Comment: sorry for my typo in the first posting. it is not able to find the "flight" tab. @FindBy(id="tab-flight-tab-flp")
       WebElement flightTab;

Answer (score 1):

Is you want get `Flights` button ?

[image: picture]

It will achieve with :

1. Find by `id` :

   `@FindBy(id="tab-flight-tab-hp")`
2. Find by `xpath` :

   `@FindBy(xpath="//button[@id='tab-flight-tab-hp']")`